# Escape "<" and ">" in xsl <input/>

Tags: xslt, attributes, escaping

I need to escape the `<` and `>` inside an `<input/>` of XML

Here is the problem:

```
<input type="submit" 
       class="button" 
       value="Search" 
       formaction
       ="APage.aspx?Module=Module1&amp;XMLType=XMLType1&amp;Mode=Search&amp;SessionId=<xsl:value-of select="/../SESSIONID"/>">
</input>
```

I tried `&lt;SessionId=<xsl:value-of select="/../SESSIONID"/&gt;`

It returns an error saying `expecting /> before /../SESSIONID`

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside an attribute value you cannot put an XSL tag or have unescaped quotation marks `"` (use the entity `&quot;` instead).

You can use braces `{}` to insert an XPath expression in the attribute value:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" 
    formaction="APage.aspx?Module=Module1&amp;XMLType=XMLType1&amp;Mode=Search&amp;SessionId={/../SESSIONID}" 
    value="Search"/>
```

or use the `xsl:attribute` element:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" 
    value="Search">
    <xsl:attribute name="formaction">APage.aspx?Module=Module1&amp;XMLType=XMLType1&amp;Mode=Search&amp;SessionId=<xsl:value-of select="/../SESSIONID)"/></xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

Comment: Additional info: the braces are called an [Attribute Value Template (AVT)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).